# Is this deduction logically true?

Tags: logic

So I have this:

$$A\vee (B\wedge C)\\ B\to D\\ C\to E\\ D\wedge E\to F\\ \sim A$$
$$--------$$
$$\therefore F $$

I know some rules like $p\to q \wedge q \therefore q$ but confused where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the deduction is correct, and here's why:

You have the statements $A \vee (B \wedge C)$ and $\sim A$, which both have to be true. That means that $A$ is false, and that $B \wedge C$ is true. In order for $B \wedge C$ to be true, both $B$ and $C$ need to be true.

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators), for the if statement to be true, because the predicate is already true, the conclusion HAS to be true. Therefore, from $B \rightarrow D$, we get that $D$ is true, and likewise, from $C \rightarrow E$, $E$ is true.

Finally, because $D$ and $E$ are both true, we have that $D \wedge E$ is true, and  ergo, $F$ is true, which is our conclusion.

Comment: Of course, make sure that you can get to each step on your own! :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's be clear in our vocabulary. Logically, an argument itself is not true or untrue: its premises and conclusions can be true or false, but being true or false is not a property of an argument.

A deductive argument is either ***valid***, or else not valid (invalid). An argument form is *valid* if and only if the conclusion *logically* follows from the premises. This means that *whenever the premises are true, the conclusion is necessarily true.*

A ***sound*** argument is a *valid* argument *whose premises are all true* (and thereby, validity guarantees that the conclusion is necessarily true).

---

Depending on the rules of inference you are working with, I'd start with the inference $$A \lor (B \land C)\\\lnot A\\\therefore B\land C$$

Then you can use can use $\land$-Elimination to obtain each of $B$, $C$:

$$B \land C, \quad \therefore B,\;\;\text{ and }\;\;B \land C, \quad \therefore C.$$

Now that we've derived $B$ we can use modus ponens to obtain $D$, and similarly, having derived $C$, we can use modus ponens to obtain $E$.

Next, using $\;\land$-Introduction we have $$D, E \\ \therefore (D \land E)$$

One more application of modus ponens takes us to the desired conclusion: $$[(D \land E)\rightarrow F]\\ (D \land E)\\ \therefore F$$

Comment: It is logically valid. So if the premises are true, the conclusion is necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Work backwards.  You are trying to conclude $F$, and the only premise you have that mentions $F$ is the fourth one, $D\land E\to F$, so the last step in the proof must be to conclude $F$ from $D\land E \to F$, via the rule that says that you can conclude $z$ from $y\to z$ and $y$.

You have $D\land E\to F$, so you will also need to have shown $D\land E$.  How can you make $D\land E$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\neg A$ and $A\vee (B\wedge C)$, we have $B\wedge C$ so $B$ and $C$ hold. Now $B$ and $B\to D$ give $D$ whereas $C$ and $C\to E$ give $E$. Thus we have $D\wedge E$, but then $(D\wedge E)\to F$ gives $F$.

Comment: See @amWhy's answer for a more detailed version of this. Think of mine as a summary :)

Answer (score 1):

If we use Natural Deduction rules, we can formalise amWhy's derivation as follows (we have 5 assumptions) :

*1)* assume : $\lnot A \rightarrow (B \land C)$ that is equivalent to : $A \lor (B \land C)$ --- Ass n°1

*2)* assume : $\lnot A$ --- Ass n°5

*3)* deduce $(B \land C)$ from 1) and 2) by $\rightarrow$-elim

*4)* deduce $B$ from 3) by $\land$-elim

*5)* deduce $C$ from 3) by $\land$-elim

*6)* assume : $B \rightarrow D$ --- Ass n°2

*7)* deduce $D$ from 4) and 6) by $\rightarrow$-elim

*8)* assume : $C \rightarrow E$ --- Ass n°3

*9)* deduce $E$ from 5) and 7) by $\rightarrow$-elim

*10)* deduce $D \land E$ from 7) and 9) by $\land$-intro

*11)* assume : $(D \land E) \rightarrow F$ --- ass n°4

*12)* deduce $F$ from 10) and 11) by $\rightarrow$-elim

The only flow is with the *equivalence* in *1)*; we need a deduction of it, because otherwise we must appeal to truth-tables (the *equivalence* is a TAUTOLOGY), and this will force us to *classical* logic.

I think that step *1)* can be justified in this way :

*a)* assume $A$

*b)* assume $\lnot A$

*c)* deduce $\bot$ by $\lnot$-elim

*d)* deduce $\lnot A \rightarrow (B \land C)$ by $\lnot$-intro

*e)* assume $(B \land C)$

*f)* deduce $\lnot A \rightarrow (B \land C)$ by $\rightarrow$-intro

*g)* assume $A \lor (B \land C)$

*h)* deduce $\lnot A \rightarrow (B \land C)$ by $\lor$-elim and dicharge *a)* and *e)*.